# Is there any way to make toggle down menu appear just when i click on the image?

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I want to make that menu to appear only when i press on he image, not everytime i load or resize the page. Here is a codepen with project.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
                $('nav').toggleClass('active');
            })
        })
    </script>
```

https://codepen.io/Denis1337/pen/jgybeW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is showing the menu when resize because it is already active from the beginning. Remove `active` from `nav` and it should work.

```
<header>
 <nav>
   <ul id="dropdown">
     <li><a class="active" href="index.html" >Acasa</a></li>
     <li><a href="#main-despre" >Despre noi</a></li>
     <li><a href="galerie.html" >Galerie</a></li>
     <li><a href="#team-section">Salon</a></li>
     <li><a href="#footer" >Contact</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact2.html" >Trimite-ne un mesaj</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
 <div class="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</header>
```

Comment: I feel so bad for that, it seems to be so easy but i actually wasted 2h trying to fix that. Thanks a lot